# Filtering numbers from array

Tags: javascript

Here I want to filter numbers from `asNum` array

```
self.protocolArray = [{
    protocol: "OSPF",
    asNum: [0, "", undefined, null, 1, 2]
}];

for (var j = 0; j < self.protocolArray.length; j++) {
    self.protocolArray[j].asNum.forEach(function (asNumitem) {
        if (asNumitem && (asNumitem !== "")) {
            asNumStoreData.items.push({
                "name": asNumitem.toString(),
                "value": asNumitem.toString(),
                "selected": "false"
            });
        }
    });
}
```

expected result `{items:[0,1,2]}`

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

To check if a number exists, use `isNaN` and `parseFloat`.

```
var result = [];
asNum.forEach(function(asNumItem){
    if (!isNaN(parseFloat(asNumItem)) && isFinite(asNumItem))
        result.push(asNumItem);
});
```

Comment: Why not just mark as duplicate instead of copypasting an existing answer?